# How to digitally sign .tlb(type library) files?

Tags: c#, digital-signature, typelib

I want to digitally sign .tlb file. Can I know how to sign the .tlb files.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is that on windows c++?

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar, No, It is on c#

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar, would like to sign .tld file using any programming language is fine for me. But preferred to do in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to implement your own signing logic if you have time and patience to build a tool using c# and standard encryption libraries included with .Net framework.

If this is intended for build process usage, old version of VS had a tool called signtool.exe. Check out this documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe

You will have to obtain it from older distribution. Please keep in mind that this does not stop reading program from proceeding without checking for digital certificate.

Otherwise, third parties including Microsoft and Verisign do provide their own signing tools. Please go through this article for detailed steps - https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/microsoft-digital-signatures/

Comment: When I tried to sign .tlb file using SignTool.exe then SigTool throws an error:
"SignTool Error: This file format cannot be signed because it is not recognized.
SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign: D:\Demo\Common.tlb"

Comment: @KalyaniReddy : I havent had time to check this out, will do it tonight.